# LambdaConversionException when mixing method reference and generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8, method-reference

The code below compiles fine but throws an exception at runtime. Is this the expected behaviour and why?

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A<Integer> a = new A<> ();
  System.out.println(a.min()); //prints null as expected
  System.out.println(a.max()); //throws exception
}

static class A<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> {
  Stream<T> s = Stream.empty();
  public T min() { return s.min((t1, t2) -> t1.compareTo(t2)).orElse(null); }
  public T max() { return s.max(T::compareTo).orElse(null); }
}
```

Output:

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at abc$A.max(abc.java:19)
    at abc.main(abc.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type class java.lang.Number; not a subtype of implementation type interface java.lang.Comparable
    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:233)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: I get the expected `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed` with java 1.8.0_60

Comment: @AlexisC. Weird (at least your output makes more sense than mine) - I'm on 1.8.0_60 too - Windows x64.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the first line (with the min) so the stream is open?

Comment: @SkinnyJ Same thing - I still get the exception

Comment: Indeed that's weird, I'm on OS X 10.11.1 if that helps.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior as @AlexisC. 1.8.0_60 Windows x64

Comment: Hmm, JDK 1.8.0_60 Windows 10 x64, I get the same behaviour as the OP, i.e. `LambdaConversionException` is thrown... I do have `IllegalStateException` if I change `max` argument to `(t1, t2) -> t1.compareTo(t2)` instead of `T::compareTo`.

Comment: Looks like I get the `LambdaConversionException` with ECJ. Are you sure you're not using that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031244/lambdaconversionexception-with-generics-jvm-bug) looks similar but I can reproduce that one even with javac 1.8.0_60, which I cannot do with the example in this case.

Comment: @assylias what if you make `T` only extend `Comparable` (not `Number`)

Comment: Of course, you could just use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `T::compareTo` but it’s a pity that there are still problems with multiple bounds…

Comment: @SkinnyJ: I can still reproduce the problem of that question with `jdk1.8.0_60`

Comment: @Holger I must have been unclear. Agree, I can reproduce the problem of that question with 1.8.0_60; but I can't reproduce THIS question's problem with that compiler (although I can with ECJ). To me indicates that the issues are slightly different.

Comment: @SkinnyJ: I see. Well, there's at least [something](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058112) which has been fixed in `u45`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler is involved. When using an older compiler, like the one integrated into Netbeans, you get the problem, even if the runtime is uptodate.

Comment: @SkinnyJ removing Number solves the problem but there seems to be a bug anyway...

Comment: Apparently it is a bug

Comment: I get the `LambdaConversionException` with Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2) compiler, but works fine with JDK 1.8.0_51 compiler (Windows).  Are you using Eclipse?  Which version.  Smells like a bug.

Comment: @assylias right but it points to the multiple bonds issue (or something similar). Can you confirm if you are compiling with eclipse or javac?

Comment: @SkinnyJ It seems to be a Netbeans problem - when running the same from the command line I get the expected output but when running from Netbeans (which uses javac) I get the output in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a Netbeans issue and I can't reproduce the problem when using javac from the command line. I have filed a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256349).

Comment: I don't think it is Netbeans fault, check my answer, it was reported as a bug in the complier

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I don't think that's the case. That bug was fixed in 8u40 and I have the problem with 8u60 + the code compiles and runs fine with javac (but not in Netbeans).

Comment: If you turn off "compile on save", the problem disappears. Perhaps that turns off the Netbeans compiler and switches to javac?

Answer (score 6):

Your code wouldn't work even if you use lambdas instead of method references because the stream is already exhausted

```
 System.out.println(a.min()); 
 System.out.println(a.max()); // exhausted
```

Streams are one off. But lets leave this apart. When you use the method reference version, it is capturing `Number` as a type parameter and not `Comparable` where `Number` has no `compareTo` **maybe** because `Number` is more specific here.
If you just use `Comparable` it will work fine

```
  static class A<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    Stream<T> s = Stream.empty();
    public T min() { return s.min((t1, t2) -> t1.compareTo(t2)).orElse(null); }
    public T max() {
        T t = s.max(T::compareTo).orElse(null);
        return t; }
 }

System.out.println(a.max()); //null
```

IMO (just to be cautious) : I believe it is a bug.

What I actually believe: It is definitely a bug.

**Edit:** It turns out that this was actually a bug and it was fixed as confirmed by Brian Goetz. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058112. According to the bug database, this was fixed in [8u40](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/versions/16510)

Answer (score 4):

The call site initialization problem is addressed through [JDK-8058112](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058112)
available in JDK 8u40 b17 or later.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are facing this issue in 2017 with `java8 1.8.0_141`, there's another filed bug report [JDK-8142476](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8142476) and the fix version is `java9` only.