# Enum, interfaces and (Java 8) lambdas: code compiles but fails at runtime; is this expected?

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference

JDK is Oracle' JDK 1.8u65 but the problem has been seen with "as low as" 1.8u25 as well.

Here is the full SSCCE:

```
public final class Foo
{
    private interface X
    {
        default void x()
        {
        }
    }

    private enum E1
        implements X
    {
        INSTANCE,
        ;
    }

    private enum E2
        implements X
    {
        INSTANCE,
        ;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        Stream.of(E1.INSTANCE, E2.INSTANCE).forEach(X::x);
    }
}
```

This code compiles; but it fails at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at com.github.fge.grappa.debugger.main.Foo.main(Foo.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type class java.lang.Enum; not a subtype of implementation type interface com.github.fge.grappa.debugger.main.Foo$X
    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:233)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
    ... 8 more
```

Fixing it in code is "easy"; in the main method, you just have to:

```
// Note the <X>
Stream.<X>of(E1.INSTANCE, E2.INSTANCE).forEach(X::x);
```

**EDIT** There is in fact a second way, as mentioned in the accepted answer... Replace the method reference with a lambda:

```
Stream.of(E1.INSTANCE, E2.INSTANCE).forEach(x -> x.x());
```

So, uh. What happens here? Why does the initial code compile in the first place? I'd have expected the compiler to notice that the method reference was not on anything `Enum<?>` but on `X`, but no...

What am I missing? Is this a bug in the compiler? A misunderstanding of mine?

Comment: Perhaps a related `javac` bug: [JDK-8141508](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141508) although it seems to deal with intersecting types.

Comment: @Tunaki interesting; I'll read through this issue, maybe it's the same...

Comment: It *is* an intersecting type. The inferred type of `Stream.of(E1.INSTANCE,E2.INSTANCE)` is `Stream<Enum<?>&Foo.X>`, according to my Eclipse.

Comment: @RealSkeptic How were you able to determine that? My Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 shows me a `Stream<? extends Enum<?>>`

Comment: @Tunaki Easy: you assign it to an unrelated variable, like `int i = Stream.of(...)`, and see what the error message complains about. :-)

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nice, I see! :) There I guess this is the same bug as above.

Comment: @Tunaki agreed; I'd like to add a link to this question to the bug in question but the requirements for having an account on OpenJDK's bug system are blurry at best... *sigh*

Comment: @RealSkeptic a question if you don't mind; Eclipse still uses ECJ instead of plain javac, right? So, does it mean that ECJ shares the same bug?

Comment: @fge I would think so. The fact that it reports two different types - one when hovering over the `of` or `forEach`, which just says it's a stream of Enums, and one when I use the trick above means that the compiler itself is a bit confused. I think one of these allows the `X::x`, but the other writes byte code that references the wrong type.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems you've hit [JDK-8141508](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8141508), which is indeed a bug of `javac` when dealing with intersection types and method-references. It is scheduled to be fixed in Java 9.

Quoting [a mail from Remi Forax](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-November/009824.html):

> javac has trouble with intersection type that are target type of a lambda and method reference,
>   Usually when there is an intersection type, javac substitute it by the first type of the intersection type and add cast when necessary.
>
> Let suppose we have this code,
>
> ```
> public class Intersection {
>       interface I {
>       }
>       interface J {
>           void foo();
>       }
>
>       static <T extends I & J> void bar(T t) {
>           Runnable r = t::foo;
>       } 
>
>       public static void main(String[] args) {
>           class A implements I, J { public void foo() {} }
>           bar(new A());
>       }
>   }
> ```
>
> Currently, javac generates a method reference on J::foo with an invokedynamic that takes an I as parameter, hence it fails at runtime.
>   javac should de-sugar t::foo into a lambda that take an I and then add a cast to J like for a call to a method of an intersection type.
>
> So the workaround is to use a lambda instead,
>
> ```
> Runnable r = t -> t.foo();
> ```
>
> I've already seen this bug somewhere but was not able to find a corresponding bug report in the database :(

In your code, the Stream created by `Stream.of(E1.INSTANCE, E2.INSTANCE)` is of type `Stream<Enum<?>&Foo.X>`, which combines all the elements of the bug: intersecting types and method-references.

As noted by Remi Forax, a work-around would be:

```
Stream.of(E1.INSTANCE, E2.INSTANCE).forEach(x -> x.x());
```

i.e. using an explicit lambda expression instead of a method-reference.

Comment: Yep, this workaround also works (I have tested it before you answered and stumbled upon this very mail as well, after you linked to the bug). Good digging! Thanks!

Comment: I opened an enhancement request on Jetbrains for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148528. I guess a similar request could be opened for Eclipse :)

Comment: @fge Yes I searched their Bugzilla but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The older bug that Remi Forax didn’t find is [JDK-8058112](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058112). Maybe the fact that it is already closed as allegedly fixed hindered finding it. Note that the examples of [the related older question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27031244/2711488) still fail with recent JDKs…