# Weird exception "Invalid receiver type class java.lang.Object; not a subtype of ..."

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm getting this strange exception in code run using jre1.8.0_66:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at main
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type class java.lang.Object; not a subtype of implementation type interface Fruit
    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:233)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
    ... 3 more
```

What's it mean?  The code is as follows:

```
public static interface Fruit {

    int getPickingMonth();
}

public static class Apple implements Fruit, Serializable {

    @Override
    public int getPickingMonth() {
        return 11;
    }
}

public static class Orange implements Fruit, Serializable {

    @Override
    public int getPickingMonth() {
        return 2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Apple> apples = Arrays.asList(new Apple());
    List<Orange> oranges = Arrays.asList(new Orange());

    Stream.of(apples.stream(), oranges.stream())
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .map(Fruit::getPickingMonth)  // exception occurs on this line
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
}
```

The exception goes away if I change `Fruit::getPickingMonth` to `x -> x.getPickingMonth()`.

**For what it's worth:** The exception also goes away if I remove `Serializable` from either class.  But returns if I add another, equivalent interface to both classes, e.g. `Cloneable` or some custom interface.

Comment: This seems very related to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33925551/1743880) which is a `javac` bug.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You ran into the same compiler bug that has been discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33925551/1743880) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27031244/2711488).

The problem occurs whenever an intersection type is involved and you are using a method reference using a receiver type other than the first one (the first type is the one that will remain after type erasure).

So when you replace the method reference with a lambda expression, you are not affected by the bug anymore. If you remove the `Serializable` from the types instead, the inferred element type of the `Stream` will be `Fruit`, i.e. not an intersection type, and again the problem does not occur. But with the two element types implementing `Fruit` and `Serializable`, the compiler will infer the element type `Object&Fruit&Serializable` and the raw type will be `Object` which provokes the error when using a method reference with the receiver type `Fruit`. You can easily work around this:

```
Stream.of(apples.stream(), oranges.stream())
        .<Fruit>flatMap(Function.identity())
        .map(Fruit::getPickingMonth) // no more exception on this line
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

The compiled code will be identical to your original, but the formal result type of the `flatMap` operation will be `Stream<Fruit>`, ignoring all other artifacts of the inferred intersection type. As a consequence the method reference `Fruit::getPickingMonth` will implement the type `Function<Fruit,Integer>` instead of `Function<Object&Fruit&Serializable,Integer>` and the compiler bug does not materialize.

But note that your code is unnecessarily complicated. You can simply use

```
Stream.<Fruit>concat(apples.stream(), oranges.stream())
        .map(Fruit::getPickingMonth) // no more exception on this line
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I couldn't follow the other two discussions but this answer is concise and extremely easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've replaced `Arrays.stream(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).map(EnumSuperInterface::getErrorCode))` with `Stream.<EnumSuperInterface>of(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).map(EnumSuperInterface::getErrorCode))` and it is working now!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are just trying to reference a method from the interface with no return.

ie:

```
Fruit::getPickingMonth; //cant return anything
```

I would imagine you would want something like

```
Apple::getPickingMonth;
or
Orange::getPickingMonth;
```

Instead

If the above isn't the solution it might be a casting issue where the compiler doesn't know what to return on the bytecode level.

There are questions like this on StackOverflow

[Lambda Referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)

[Lambda Conversion Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031244/lambdaconversionexception-with-generics-jvm-bug)