# Changing the order of two type parameter bounds causes Java runtime error

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, type-bounds

The following code crashes at runtime but if you change that one line so that `Model & Serializable` becomes `Serializable & Model`, then it runs fine. Can anyone explain what is going on? Is this a bug in Java? Doesn't seem like the order of type bounds should matter.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

interface Model {
    void foo();
}

class ModelA implements Model, Serializable {
    public void foo() {

    }
}

class MemcachedHelper<T extends Serializable> {
    T getCached(String key, Maker<T> make) {
        return make.get();
    }
    interface Maker<U extends Serializable> {
        U get();
    }
}

class Query {
    Object getResult() {
        return new ModelA();
    }
}
public class Main {

    // private static <T extends Serializable & Model>
    private static <T extends Model & Serializable>
    T getModel(Class<T> modelClass, MemcachedHelper<T> cache) {
        String key = "key:" + modelClass.getSimpleName();
        T thing = cache.getCached(key, () -> {
            Query q = new Query();
            return (T)q.getResult();
        });
        return thing;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemcachedHelper<ModelA> cache = new MemcachedHelper<>();
        Model thing = getModel(ModelA.class, cache);
        System.out.printf("Got thing: %s\n", thing);
    }

}
```

The runtime error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
  at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341)
  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
  at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
  at Main.getModel(Main.java:33)
  at Main.main(Main.java:42)
  ...  
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Type mismatch for lambda expected return: interface Model is not convertible to interface java.io.Serializable
  at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:286)
  at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303)
  at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)
  ... 9 more
```

This is JDK version 1.8.0_101.

Comment: I think, it’s a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27031244/2711488) though here, the problematic type is the return type rather than the receiver type, but in either case, the wrong handling of intersection types is the same.

Answer (score 4):

There is a corner case, where the order of the type bounds matter. The *raw* method signature of a generic method or a method referring to type variables is determined by the first type bound.

So if you declare the `T` type parameter of `getModel` as `<T extends Model & Serializable>`, it’s raw return type will be `Model`, but when you declare it as `<T extends Serializable & Model>` it’s raw return type will be `Serializable`.

If you declare it as `<T extends Object & Serializable & Model>`, its raw return type will be `Object`.

Apparently, `javac` uses the same strategy for the synthetic method created for the lambda expression returning `T`. However, since the target type `Maker<U extends Serializable>` has the functional signature `() -> U`, it’s raw signature is `() -> Serializable`. So when you use the declarations of `getModel`’s `T` that cause the raw return type to be `Object` or `Model`, it doesn’t match the specified target type’s signature expecting the return type to be compatible with `Serializable`.

To illustrate, how the raw signatures interact here, if you change the declaration of `Maker` to `interface Maker<U extends Object & Serializable>`, its raw functional signature’s return type will be `Object`, which will be compatible with all of `T`’s declaration variants.

But, of course, these are implementation details. The way you declare it *should not* affect the correct­ness of the code, even if the raw code differs, it should not suddenly break. This can be considered a compiler bug. As you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27031244/2711488), the mistreatment of intersection types has a longer tradition. The problem would go away, if the compiler just chooses a raw return type for the synthetic method matching the raw functional signature of the target type.

Comment: That makes sense. I notice your answer in that other question is over 2 years old. I would think that fixing a language level bug like this would be high priority, but maybe the developers of Java don't agree.

Comment: Well, there was the misleading statement that the issue was fixed, whereas the fix wasn’t broad enough. It might have turned out, that a full fix needs deeper changes to  `javac` (there are a lot more open issues), so perhaps some developers think that a complete redesign would help more than adding fix after fix, but this would preclude a fast solution. There are also far less developers working on the compiler as you might think (you can’t just reassign developers from other fields to it, you need compiler experts)…